# Are plugins like WP Robot considered as spammy by the community?

Tags: automation

WP Robot looks like a very powerful plugin, but one which could be used for all sorts of spammy websites. Just wondering what the general community opinion is of these plugins? Are they useful or damaging to a website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what answer you are looking for. Plugins are not something that you directly see when you look at site. Not something site's reputation is based on.

I hadn't looked into this specific plugin, but as any of this kind it likely can be used both for perfectly legit and absolutely spammy purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Can't really see why should be seen as spam. All depends on you and how you are using it.
It's like all car drivers will be seen as suiciders because one hitted a tree in purpose :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WP Robot to create some spammy blog that merely aggregates junk content from other peoples blogs then I would see it as being misused by whoever set up the blog, in this case it would be you.

Not all content aggregation / auto posting plugins are used for spam. I've used a couple before to aggregate content from credible websites for a watch website I created a long time ago to make some AdSense cash, it was successful because nobody saw it as a spam blog, but a useful one.

A bad mechanic always blames his tools, not himself. I guess the same metaphor applies to this and all situations that use such plugins.

Answer (score 1):

If you use WP Robot too much your blog will be seen as a bot or scraper site. I would rather mix the automatically created content with handwritten one then set it to autopilot.
The trick is to use the features of WP Robot to minimize your work and maximise the worth for the reader.
And yes: Automation plugins are almost always seen as something "blackhat".